# What would be better in terms of performance wise Kafka to s3 connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Google didn't help me, so I want to ask you. I have a lot of kafka topics I have seend many articles about java heap memory and so on   but I need some guidance
I have a lot of kafka topics that I need to go to one s 3 bucket using s3 sink connector
How do you go about running multiple instances of s3 sink connector ? Should I create multiple systemd scripts for each s3 connector and multiple copies of kafka start scripts ? or use one script and run it multiple times poiting to different s3 connector properites configs for each topic?  Is this better performance than using single connector for all the topics since they all going to the same bucket ?

How do i calculate the memory needed
lets say i have
topic 1 5000 Messages
tpic2  2000 Messages
and topic 3 500 Messages

How do I balance the load requirements vs the memory requirements vs what is available on the server
how much memory do I need  in case I have a server with lets say 4 GB

Comment: _How do you go about running multiple instances of s3 sink connector_ - You'd use multiple servers. You can configure multiple tasks (consumer threads) per connector group (one connector configuration), that would distribute over all servers

Comment: how do you configure consumer threads ?  for s3 sink connector ?  any examples ? can use one script for multiple config files kakfa-run-class

Comment: you wouldn't use kafka-run-class directly, you'd use connect-distributed.. When you post a connector, tasks.max is a required field, and you can put multiple topics or a regex pattern to consume into a single connector config

Comment: hello thanks for your help ooh so per performance is it better to use multiple topics in one connector configs  using the connect-dstributed script or run multiple configs with  one connect-distributed script or make different connect-distributed scripts pointing to different configs  with their own sets of memory values for xmax memory etc .. Each topic these scenarios present dilemmas to me in terms of management of different services especially if you have more than 10 topics ?

Comment: I understand i just noticed that the script calls the run class so thats why i use it as a reference I also noticed connect stand alone is kinda the same script as conncet distributed sh script unless I m missing some thing.

Comment: As mentioned, you'd ideally use a cluster of connect servers running distributed mode. As far as memory usage is concerned, it really depends on the flush sizes and partitioning, but I've ran a cluster consuming hundreds of topics with thousands of partitions and it never has OOM'd with 8g of heap space